# Searching for a title thats 'starts with' in python?

Tags: python

So I have a list of names

```
name_list = ["John Smith", "John Wrinkle", "John Wayne", "David John", "David Wrinkle", "David Wayne"]
```

I want to be able to search, for example, `John` and

```
John Smith
John Wrinkle
John Wayne
```

will display. At the moment my code will display

```
John Smith
John Wrinkle
John Wayne
David John
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code

```
search = input(str("Search: "))
search = search.lower()
matches = [name for name in name_list if search in name]
for i in matches:
    if(search == ""):
        print("Empty search field")
        break
    else:
        i = i.title()
        print(i)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your `matches` to:

```
matches = [name for name in name_list if name.startswith(search)]
```

You can also make some changes to your code:

```
# You can do this in one go
search = input(str("Search: ")).lower()

# Why bother looping if search string wasn't provided.
if not search:
    print("Empty search field")
else:
             # This can be a generator
    for i in (name for name in name_list if name.startswith(search)):
        print(i.title())
```

Comment: Why would naming it `search` shadow the `search` in `re.search`?  That's the whole point of namespaces which (according to the zen) are a honking great idea (lets do more of those!) ...

Comment: I get a `TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable`

Comment: Post the full traceback @LiamEmery

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure how to make it look like `this`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/liamemery/PycharmProjects/assignmenttwo/QuestionTwo.py", line 62, in <module>
    startsWith()
  File "/Users/liamemery/PycharmProjects/assignmenttwo/QuestionTwo.py", line 28, in startsWith
    matchStartWith = [movie for movie in movies_list if searchStr in movie.startswith(searchStr)]
  File "/Users/liamemery/PycharmProjects/assignmenttwo/QuestionTwo.py", line 28, in <listcomp>
    matchStartWith = [movie for movie in movies_list if searchStr in movie.startswith(searchStr)]
TypeError: argument of type 'bool' is not iterable

Comment: @mgilson, sorry brain stopped working, I think I was thinking of something else, removed the suggestion. Liam, `matchStartWith = [movie for movie in movies_list if searchStr in movie.startswith(searchStr)]` should be `matchStartWith = [movie for movie in movies_list if movie.startswith(searchStr)]`